# How to Convert an SVN import to an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I have checked out the repo of an `Android` application using `Subeclipse` (File > Import > Checkout from SVN). But in `Eclipse` it just shows up as a folder. It can't be run as an android project. How to fix this? How to convert this project to an Android project so that I could build it using adt?

Edit : I'm using Eclise 3.7 Indigo in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the project from SVN to local file system first:

```
svn checkout URL /Users/Home/myproject
```

Then create an Android project and import it as existing source (File -> New -> Android Project):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem i had is after importing an android project into eclipse, it doesn't work when run. Just try this. This method worked for me.

1. Import the project from svn into eclipse in the normal way.
2. Go to properties -> java build path -> order and export
3. You will see partially selected source packages and libraries which are not selected. Just select all libraries and click OK.
4. Restart eclipse (Important to restart) and run project as android application.
5. Enjoy your working app.

Answer (score 0):

TO convert SVN project to android project

1) check out your project to file system.

like F:\projects\yourproject

2) go to eclipse.

File -> NEW-> Android Project from Existing Code

browse till F:\projects (important browse till one level up, don't click 'yourproject' here)

now eclipse will detect android projects in folder 'projects' and list them .

now, select 'yourproject'

DONE.